# Paste as Bitmap in word

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a Bitmap image copied to the clipboard and want to paste it in the word document as a Bitmap, because if not - the resolution is low.

Here is what I am doing, once the object is copied:

```
objWdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType=4
```

But, the problem is that it's pasted as a normal image (with low resolution), but not as a Bitmap. When, I do it manually, going to paste icon and selecting paste special>bitmap then everything is fine. But, using VBS (not VBA) its not working.

Any ideas, why it might be happening?

Comment: No idea, but have you also tried DataType=5? Perhaps that will work differently... You might also try recording a macro in Word when pasting manually, just to see if that uses something different.

Comment: I have tried changing the DataType to 5, but nothing differs. As per recording macro, the source looks as: `Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteBitmap, Placement:= wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False`. I have converted is to: `Selection.PasteSpecial Link=False, DataType=wdPasteBitmap, Placement= wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon=False`, but then there is an error: `The specified data type is unavailable.`

Comment: The 4 you're using is correct for wdPasteBitmap, which of course you can't use in VBS. I'm out of ideas - Word must be doing something in the UI that isn't being emulated by automation. Further thought: what happens if you use Shapes.AddPicture or InlineShapes.AddPicture from a file? Is the result any better?

Comment: Your code seems ok and should work as expected. What happens if you do the same from VBA, e.g. using `Selection.PasteSpecial DataType=4` in the *Immediate Window* of the VBA editor?